Proxy Issue with Playwright Python
all. So, I am using brightdata proxies with playwright code with the code -
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright
import os
import time

def run():
    with sync_playwright() as p:
        browser = p.firefox.launch(
            headless=False,
            proxy={
                'server': 'http://XXXXXX:XXXXX', 
                'username': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
                'password': 'xxxxxxxxx'  
        )

        page = browser.new_page()

        # Navigate to the website to check IP
        page.goto('https://www.whatismyip.com/')
        time.sleep(3)
        # Close the browser after interaction
        browser.close()
run()

For datacenter/normal proxies its working fine but when using residential rotating proxy. its throwing me an error.
"""
  File "D:\pythonProject\AllProjects\venv\Lib\site-packages\playwright\_impl\_connection.py", line 59, in send
    return await self._connection.wrap_api_call(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\pythonProject\AllProjects\venv\Lib\site-packages\playwright\_impl\_connection.py", line 513, in wrap_api_call
    raise rewrite_error(error, f"{parsed_st['apiName']}: {error}") from None
playwright._impl._errors.Error: Page.goto: NS_ERROR_PROXY_FORBIDDEN
Call log:
navigating to "https://www.whatismyip.com/", waiting until "load" """"

In their Documentation, they mentioned to install the certification for using this proxy which I did but still getting the error. Can anyone help me on this?
I tried using other brightdata residential proxies, but all were giving me the same error message.

I have ran your code with my account credentials and it works great. The page loads. Make sure your account has residential permission. Please contact your account manager and make sure that your residential zone is setup correctly.
